# How to set opacity for the border with CurrentColor?

Tags: css, border, opacity, css-variables

I customize the link. I want the *border-color* to depend on the *color*. For this I use CurrentColor.

**How to make *border-bottom* with opacity 0.5?**

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
  border-bottom: 1px solid CurrentColor;
}
```

```html
<a href="/">Some link</a>
```

I have one solution, but I'm not sure that it is the best.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, CurrentColor, transparent 50%) 0 100% repeat-x;
  background-size: 10px 1px;
}
```

```html
<a href="/">Some link</a>
```

This solution doesn’t work.

```css
a {
  --color: blue;
  
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(blue);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(var(--color), 0.5);
}
```

```html
<a href="/">Some link</a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With CSS variables you need to do something like this:

```css
a {
  --color: 0,0,255;
  
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(var(--color));
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(var(--color), 0.2);
}
```

```html
<a href="/">Some link</a>
```

For the gradient solution you may create two gradients. A bottom one with the `currentColor` and a top one with the background color *(white in this case)* and adjust the opacity of the top one to control the opacity of the bottom one:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
  background-image: 
   linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.8), rgba(255,255,255,0.8)),
   linear-gradient(CurrentColor, CurrentColor);
  background-position:bottom;
  background-size:100% 1px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;

}
```

```html
<a href="/">Some link</a>
```

You can also use pseudo-element and opacity:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
  position:relative;
}
a:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  height:1px;
  background:currentColor;
  opacity:0.2;
}
```

```html
<a href="/">Some link</a>
```

Another idea is to use `box-shadow` like we did with gradient by having two layers:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
  box-shadow:
    0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.8),
    0 1px 0 0 currentColor;
}
```

```html
<a href="/">Some link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It because you set `--color: blue` and it not rgb color you have to set `rgb` color..
 the `a` of rgba is the opacity

```css
a {
  --color: 1,1,1;
  
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--color);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(var(--color), 0.2);
}
```

```html
<a href="/">Some link</a>
```

You can convert color to rgb here:https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/hex-to-rgb.html